# Help with a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help developing a two linq querys.
this is my table:

```
Id              int 
ComputadorID    int 
UtilID          int 
UtilizadorId    int 
DataInicio      datetime    
DataFim         datetime    
Removido        bit
```

what i want to do is getting a two list:
First list gets the count by hours;
Second list gets the count by day;

in the two list only count when datafim is inserted
how can i do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746 -- it's a pretty good starting reference.

Comment: i dont now to start with this :S

Comment: It will depend, at least in part, on where the data is.  Is this query over some collection of objects, or more likely over a table via EF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming DataInicio is your colum that has the days and hours you could try something like this

```
var result = from d in yourContextVar.YourTable
group d by d.DataInicio.Day into g
select new { Day=g.Key, Count=g.Count() };
```

Comment: tks a lot Ralph was that :).. i assume for the day of the week is the same. tks a lot